# Estimating flat norm distance from a planar disc

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, fa.functional-analysis

Let $D\subset\mathbb R^2\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a unit planar disc in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $S$ be an orientable two-dimensional surface in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\partial S=\partial D$. Of course, we have $area(S)\ge area(D)$. Assume that $area(S)< area(D)+\delta$ where $\delta>0$ is small.

Then $S$ is close to $D$ in the following sense: there is a 3-dimensional surface $F$ filling the gap between $S$ and $D$ such that $volume(F)<\varepsilon(\delta)$ where $\varepsilon(\delta)\to 0$ as $\delta\to 0$ ($n$ is fixed). "Filling the gap" means that $\partial F=S-D$.

This fact immediately follows from the compactness theorem for flat norms. But this proof is indirect and does not answer the following questions (I am especially interested in the second one):

1) Are there explicit upper bounds for $\varepsilon(\delta)$? How do they depend on $\delta$ and $n$?

2) Can $\varepsilon(\delta)$ be independent of $n$? Or, equivalently, does the above fact hold true in the Hilbert space?

In the unlikely event that 2-dimensional surfaces are somehow special, what about the same questions about $m$-dimensional surfaces, for a fixed $m$?

Remarks: "Surfaces" here are Lipschitz surfaces or rectifiable currents or whatever you prefer to see in this context. Rather than talking about the filling surface $F$, one could equivalently say that the integral flat norm of $S-D$ is less than $\varepsilon(\delta)$.

Comment: Something's wrong with this "gap filling" stuff. Even in the easiest cases were $S$ is just a disc that has a small "dent" (say the surface {$(x,y,z) | x^2+y^2\leq 1, z=c\cdot(1-x^2+y^2)$}) the boundary of $F$ is $S\cup D$ not $S-D$.

Comment: No, $S-D$ is not $S\setminus D$. It is the formal sum of $S$ and $-D$ where $-D$ is $D$ taken with the opposite orientation. As a set, it equals $S\cup D$ for a generic surface.


Comment: Okay, but there is still something wrong with this. If $S$ is not entirely above or below $D$ (more wave-like), then the gap between $S$ and $D$ is no manifold.

Comment: Yes a surface may be singular, it is just a map from a manifold. If n is large enough, you can approximate everything by immersions if you really need. On the constructive side, it is easier to work with singular chains rather than surfaces.


Comment: Did you try mean-curvature-flow? If yes (and if it works) what does it give you when $n$ grows?

Comment: No, the only proof I know is via compactness theorem. I know nothing about mean curvature flow but foresee problems. How to deal with the  boundary and with topological singularities?


Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [Almgren's isoperimetric inequality](http://www.ams.org/bull/1985-13-02/S0273-0979-1985-15393-5/S0273-0979-1985-15393-5.pdf):

> Let $\Sigma$ be a $k$-surface in $\mathbb R^n$. Assume $vol _k \Sigma \le vol_k S^k$. Then one can fill $\Sigma$ by a $(k+1)$-surface with volume $\le vol_{k+1} B^{k+1}$. (Here the "surfaces" might have singularities.)

I will use it to show that there is an estimate $\epsilon(\delta)$ which does not depend on $n$.

Take $r$-nbhd $Z_r$ of $D$.
Note* that one can give an explicite estimate of $r$, independent of $n$ so that total area of $S$ outside of $Z_r$ is very small. Moving a bit $r$, one can make the length of intersection curve $\gamma=\partial Z_r\cap S$ sufficiently small. 
Use Almgren to fill $\gamma$ by a surface;
it breaks $S$ into two pieces $S=S_1+S_2$;

- the surface $S_1$ lies in $Z_r$ and $\partial S_1=\partial D$,
- the surface $S_2$ has small area and $\partial S_2=0$.

Fill both $S_1$ and $S_2$ separately:

- taking all segments from point on $S_1$ to its projection on $D$ gives a filling of $S_1-D$
- fill $S_2$ using Almgren again.

---

(*)There is a map $\mathbb R^n\to D$ which decrease distances by some factor $k=k(r)<1$ outside of $Z_r$ and $k(r)$ can be found explicitly.
So if an essential piece of $S$ is outside of $Z_r$ then the area of $S$ is essentially bigger that $area(D)$.

Say, take $f(x)=$ "sum of maximal and minimal distance to the points in $D$".
This function is convex and it is constant on $D$. 
Take Sharafutdinov retruction for the level sets of this function.

Comment: This r should go to zero along with $\delta$, shouldn't it? Then how do you prove that the area outside the r-neighborhood is small?

Comment: @Sergei. I add something to the answer.

Comment: Great! And this works in far more general setting than in the question.
